# How does "create_association()" added by "belongs_to" work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example we got two classes:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author， optional: true
end
```

Now imagine we got a @book object, then I want **create a related author from this book object**.

I thought `@book.create_author` should do two things:

1. Create one Author object, we call it @author
2. Relate @author with @book, which update `@book.author_id` to `@author.id` and save it to database

As I can see, those two things require 2 sql:

1. insert new record to authors table, get author id
2. update record in books table set book.author_id = <author id in 1)>

But when I run `@book.create_author`, I only got 1), and step 2) never happened. The result looks no difference with `Author.create`.

What might be the reason to cause this?

Comment: are you saving book?

Comment: @ David I thought if I use create_author, I don't need to save book object manually.

Comment: yes you would.. in your case it is the book that is managing the relationship ... not the author.

Comment: You are right, I print @book and notice inside object the author_id was set correctly, but it was not saved to database. This method is really confused.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you're not passing some required values in your `create_author` call. For example, does your Author model require a name? You can pass these required attributes in the `create_author` call.

Also, you're probably well advised to assign the new Author record to a variable so you can easily manipulate it if needed.

```
@author = @book.create_author(name: 'Mariam Hussein')
```

If the new record has all required attributes, it should behave as you expect. If it doesn't you can use `@author.errors` to see what the problem is with the newly created record and fix it.

(It's always worth checking the Rails docs for things like this. The `#create_association` method is described [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).)

Comment: For what I see, the new author record was inserted to database successfully. However the @book.author_id still nil.

Comment: Can you post specifics? We'll need to see the initial @book record, the command you issued to create your new author, and the resulting Author and Book records. Ideally also the result of `@author.errors`. Otherwise, we don't know what you've actually done. (Probably best to edit the question above, adding the new details at the end for clarity.)

Comment: Maybe this method doesn't perform like what I was thinking. It only do 1). About step 2) it only modify the receiver object rather than save them.

Comment: Well, there's always a difference between the copy of the record you're working with and the version saved to the database - that's standard in Rails. In your original question, you said you weren't getting an `author_id` reference in your @book object. Do I see correctly from your comment on the question now that you are actually getting that, and it's just that the @book object isn't being saved? In which case, you just need to do a `@book.save`.

Comment: I mixed the receiver object with the one in database. But still confused me is when I use `has_one`, I don't have to save, but `belongs_to` require a manually save. In the doc, their description is the same. [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) and [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one)

Comment: Well, I can replicate your result: with a model that `belongs_to :other_model, optional: true`, I don't get the `other_model_id` field in the record updated if I do `Model.first.create_other_model(name: 'foo')`, although the new OtherModel with name='foo' is created. I wouldn't usually operate on the database directly myself, and your question was about a `@book` object not a DB record. So this isn't really the question you originally asked - your issue seems at root to be an inconsistency between how `#create_association` works between has_one and belongs_to relations.

Comment: I realize what I am looking for is that "how does `belongs_to :autosave` works." By default, only save the associated object if it's a **new record**.